# Carousel ok in Site.Master, but not inside Content element

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, master-pages

My carousel picture show works well when placed inside Site.Master, but the same markup inside the Content element of an .aspx file that uses Site.Master (without the carousel snippet) displays only the alt text for each image that it cycles through.

Environment: Win10 Pro, Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.4.4, bootstrap 3.0.0

Here is the carousel snippet:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Images-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item carousel-item active">
            <img src="1945_DeHavilland_Canada_DH-98_Mosquito_FBMK26.jpg" alt="Slide #1">
        </div>
        <div class="item carousel-item">
            <img src="1969_Aerovodochody_L-29_DELFIN.jpg" alt="Slide #2">
        </div>
        <div class="item carousel-item">
            <img src="737BahamasAir.jpg" alt="Slide #3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left Right Arrows -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I just partially answered my question myself: it's in the way I am referring to the image files in the 'src' attribute's url. This works: src="../i/CarouselShow/737BahamasAir.jpg", where i is a directory off of the ASP.NET application's root. But this does not work: src="~/i/CarouselShow/737BahamasAir.jpg", nor does it work without the "~". Is using the two dots the only way to get this right?

Answer (score 0):

If the file you are using the display the carousel is inside of a subfolder, example:

/wwwroot/Content/file.aspx

Then you would have to set the image source to ../example_image.jpg (or wherever the image is stored, in this case, the image is in your web root folder.